# What is the Endpoint URL in Mule?

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to integrate salesforce with mule. In Salesforce i am using Outbound message. In outbound Message asking Endpoint URL. but i need integrate with salesforce to mule. so How i can give the Endpoint URL Address. Which Endpoint URL is suitable for connect with Mule. how can i connect and Which Endpoint Component will go to use in mule. how i receive the Outbound message in mule from salesforce. In salesforce i know the outbound message creation. I don't know the Endpoint URL. Normal Salesforce Endpoint URL link to some other Webpage. but here i should need Mule Endpoint URL. How i can give this. Please Suggest it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a http-endpoint in your mule flow, and specify to which URL it should listen to.
example of such endpoint declaration is:

```
<http:endpoint  name="myEndpoint"  address="http://myExample.info/exampleAddress" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
```

**update** 
set the address for endpoint to the available port, so if 80 is not occupied - it's ok to have it for example address="http://localhost:80/exampleAddress/"

Comment: I created by Using Http Inbound Endpoint but its not working what type of URL need to give. can give http://localhost:80/ (local host URL)

Comment: Salesforce:  I have Created one outbound Message for Contact Object in          Salesforce. In outbound message i set Endpoint URL is "http://localhost:81/". 

MULESOFT : I have Create HTTP ENDPOINT URL And One Echo Component 
Its look like this HTTP(request and Response) ----->  Echo
In HTTP Endpoint I set "http://localhost:81".

Run the Mule .

Comment: Config means? what i need to tell u

Comment: can you show us your flow where you trying to create http endpoint? the xml representation. something which contains <flow name""> and stuff

Comment: <flow name="Endpoint_TestFlow1" doc:name="Endpoint_TestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>        
    </flow>
This is my flow i am using the endpoint URL localhost

Comment: Just i want receive Salesforce outbound message from Mule Please Send the XML Flow.

Comment: can you try to publish endpoint like in example? I mean:  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="localhost:8081/operation/"/>, and call this same endpoint from salesforce. also, how do you know that it's not working? how do you test it? do you have any-kind of logger at that point?

Comment: <flow name="Endpoint_TestFlow1" doc:name="Endpoint_TestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>        
    </flow>

Yes i am using logger like the above code. In sales force i am giving some endpoint URL it same Mule Inbound Endpoint URL. In salesforce i have Create Outbound Message with end url(localhost:8081).

Comment: I would suggest you to check if port 8081 is used only by mule, second - change the endpoint definition as in example. if still not working, I'm out of ideas

Comment: no sir it's not working. i have checked with Logger also it's not listen Salesforce Outbound Message. What i do? whether the Salesforce accept end URL for "localhost:8081/operation/"

Comment: you're invoking a web-service, right? Test it via SOAP-UI or similar program. If mule receives it, then the problem is not in mule

Comment: <flow name="Endpoint_TestFlow1" doc:name="Endpoint_TestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="localhost:8081/operation/"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>        
    </flow>


now i tried your example only

Comment: Yes I am invoking Web Service Salesforce to mule. how i can do .. please can you give some steps for connect Salesforce to Mule. how i can connect this right way. i don't have idea.

Comment: import your wsdl file to soap-ui and send a request-message. You'll find out, if this problem of mule or not

Comment: where i can import WSDL file to soap-ui in mule

Comment: download soap-ui http://www.soapui.org/ . Do file->new project. Choose your wsdl location under "initial wsdl/wadl". It will create a project from your wsdl with sample requests to your operations. Send this sample request, but set mule endpoint URL first

Comment: why we should download and install the SOAP API plugin. Mule already have this plugin? then